# A problem about the proof of Künneth formula by double complex

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

In Bott-Tu's book(P107,108), they use double complex to prove Künneth formula. They define a natural map $\pi^*:C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)\rightarrow C^*(\pi^{-1}\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$, here $C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$ is a finite type de Rham - Čech complex of a manifold $M$, $F$ is another manifold with finite-dimensional homology, and $C^*(\pi^{-1}\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$ a de Rham-Čech complex of $M\times F$. And then, they define a map,$\pi_{\mathfrak{U}}^*:H^*(F) \otimes C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)\rightarrow C^*(\pi^{-1}\mathfrak U,\Omega^*),\,\pi_{\mathfrak{U}}^*([\omega_{\alpha}]\otimes\phi=\rho^*\omega_{\alpha} \wedge\pi^*\phi)$, where $\rho$ is the projection on the fiber. They stated that this $\pi_{\mathfrak{U}}^*$ is commute with $\mathrm d$, where $ \mathrm d ([\omega_{\alpha}]\otimes\phi)= [\omega_{\alpha}]\otimes \mathrm d\phi$, but clearly, $\pi_{\mathfrak{U}}^*\mathrm d ([\omega_{\alpha}]\otimes\phi)=\rho^*\omega_{\alpha} \wedge\pi^*\mathrm d\phi$, and $\mathrm d\pi_{\mathfrak{U}}^* ([\omega_{\alpha}]\otimes\phi)=(-1)^{deg( \omega_{\alpha})}\rho^*\omega_{\alpha} \wedge\pi^*\mathrm d\phi$.

I wonder if I misunderstand Bott and Tu, since in their book, they did not give either a clear definition  of $\mathrm d$ in $H^*(F) \otimes C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$, or a complete proof of Künneth formula, I hope someone read their book could help me.

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132214/on-the-proof-of-the-k%c3%bcnneth-formula-bott-tu-proposition-9-12/4142030#4142030

Comment: @Elad After reading your answer, I think I know what d is, which matches the one described in my question. However I still do not know why $\pi^*_{\mathfrak U}$ is commute with d

Comment: maps acting on tensor product are assumed to be graded commutative so $f\otimes 
 g(a\otimes b)=(-1)^{deg(g)\cdot {deg(a)}}f(a)\otimes g(b))$. See remark  14.25 in the book.

Comment: @Elad And here $g$ is the exterior derivative, then $deg(g)=1$, right?

Comment: Yes the exterior derivative has degree 1